# How to append return value of a target to another file

Tags: ant

I have a target which returns basename, This target i am calling in for loop (called arnd 1000 times)

Is there a way to append value of basename to another file?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to write all the basenames to a file? In which case see the [Concat](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html) task.

Or do you mean you want to build a different filename by concatenating the basename with something else (e.g. a path to the file), in which case presumably you could do something like this

```
${root.dir}/${your.base.name}
```